# How to setup a Vite based React app to be a progressive web app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, vite

I created a new React app based on Vite. Users should be able to install it as a progressive web app, I installed the package [vite-plugin-pwa](https://github.com/vite-pwa/vite-plugin-pwa) and modified the file *vite.config.ts* to

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), VitePWA({ registerType: 'autoUpdate' })],
  base: "./",
})
```

When running the app locally I see no install button ( I'm using Chrome ). I also had a look at the build directory, the PWA files exist ( manifest, worker, ... ). When I try to run it via `npx http-serve` I still see no install button.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you add manifest.json to your public folder then link it in your head tag?

Comment: The manifest.json ( auto generated ) lives inside the build folder. You mean something like this? `<link rel=”manifest” href=”./manifest.json”>`